# Truncating a TextView on an AppWidget layout's

Tags: android, textview, truncate, multiline, android-appwidget

people!

Well, after googling for almost two days with no result, I decided to ask here. (It's my first question.)

I'm creating a quotes widget for Android (that shows a random quote each time), so it has two TextViews and a ImageButton to get a new random quote. The first TextView shows the quote text and the second shows the quote's author. And, when the user clicks on the widget, it calls a Activity showing the quote in full screen, with scroll bars if it is needed, and so on.

The thing is that the quote's text sometimes is much long, so I was wanting to ellipsize it. But since the ellipsize doesn't work with more than 2 lines... I'm looking for ideas.

I don't know if it's necessary, but here is the layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/laySmall"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/widget_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/widgetback" >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibtNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/seta" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWdgQuote"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ibtNext"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:maxLines="3" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWdgAuthor"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically, I have 3 AppWidgets in this project, showing almost the same thing. All that change are the sizes and font sizes.

So... One idea that I had was using a custom TextView. But in a AppWidget, no way. :/

Another idea was doing something like this:

```
if (quoteText.length() > something) {
    quoteText = quoteText.substring(0, something) + "\"[...]"
}
```

The problem of this solution is where is the line breaks, because it can change the size of the string that can be showed. For example, let say a string with small words: the lines will break next to the border. Meanwhile a string that has bigger words the line breaks will be further from the border.

So... I don't know what I do. Any ideas, please?

Thanks!

(I'm having problems with the android:layout_margin, so it can be a little smaller, but I didn't have time to work on this yet.

Comment: why do you marquee the text my friend

Comment: But marquee doesnt work only for single line TextViews?

Comment: (also, should be > something + 5 , as you add 5 characters

Comment: Yeah, you right. The "+5" is necessary. About the maxLines, njzk2, it end the text in a abrupt way. Doesn't put a "..." or anything in the end.

Comment: Anyway, the idea of truncating it in code has it's problems... About the screen size, for example. :/